# is this a Vector Space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For what values of $k$ is the set $\{f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}\mid f(x)=kf(-x)\}$ a vector space? where $k$ is a real number. I think that it is for every $k$ can someone confirm?

Also, is it true that the dimension of such space is infinite?

Comment: Try $k=2$ and iterate $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f,g$ such that $f(x)=kf(-x)$ and $g(x) = kg(-x)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,

1.- $0(x) = k0(-x)$.

2.- $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x) = k(f(-x)+g(-x)) = k(f+g)(-x)$.

3.- $(af)(x) =af(x) = akf(-x) = k(af)(-x)$.

Comment: so it means that the conditions are always verified for every k? thank you

Comment: Yes. And it shows it is a subspace of the vector space of real functions.